# Unable to run server to get my views/signup.html file to run

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


app.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
// save user details to your database.
    res.send('Signed Up!');
  });

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
app.use(express.static('views'));
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

I am trying to open my views folder as the html of this application. How can I manage to do that?

Comment: In get API, You are using middleware after sending the response. Just put your `app.use(express.static('views'));` after `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));` and try to run it again

Answer (score 0):

You should use middleware in between request response cycle. But here you are using
`app.use(express.static('views'));` after sending the response.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

// Middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static('view'));

app.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
    // save user details to your database.
    res.send('Signed Up!');
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

This should fix the problem